# Request to Remove this Question from Reopen Vote Review Queue Audits

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I came across this audit in the Reopen Votes Review Queue: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/10222714. I think it's a bad audit because there has been no attempt to create an MCVE, and code is only included through links, so it perfectly fits this close reason:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Can we please have this question removed from the list of potential audits for the Reopen Votes Queue? I don't think "Leave Closed" is an unreasonable action on this question.